# How to add multiple selection into a many-to-many model in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this [small app](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/205/edit) where I'm trying to add the fruits selections of a multiple `Ember.Select` into an attribute of a model, "myfruits" of Person Alice.  However, things are broken.

Perhaps my model is set up incorrectly.

This is the Ember.Select handlebars in the html:

```
  {{view Ember.Select
      multiple="true"
      contentBinding="App.fruits"
      valueBinding="pickedFruits"
  }}
```

This is the model:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  myfruits: DS.hasMany('App.Fruit')
});

App.Fruit = DS.Model.extend({
  kind: DS.attr('string'),
  likedBy: DS.hasMany('App.Person')
});
```

This is the function that tries to save the multiple selection:

```
 pickThem: function(){
    var input_fruits = this.get('pickedFruits');
    // should I create a Fruit object for each input_fruits?
    var aperson = App.Person.createRecord({
      name: "Alice",
      myfruits: input_fruits
    });
    aperson.save();
 }
```

I feel like the problem might be I'm not creating the Fruit objects.  But I'm not sure how to make it work with the many-to-many relationship between Person and Fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need to do is as you already mentioned to create a `App.Fruit` record for every selected fruit and add it to the newly created `App.Person`.

Basically the important bit is:

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  pickThem: function(){
    var aperson = App.Person.createRecord({name: "Alice", myfruits: []});
    this.get('pickedFruits').forEach(function(item){
      aperson.get('myfruits').pushObject(App.Fruit.createRecord({kind:item, likedBy:[aperson.get('id')]}));
    });

    aperson.save();
  }
});
```

Then provide a model for your `person` template:

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  }
});
```

and in your template you can loop over the person records and inside that loop over their respective fruits:

```
{{#each model}}
  {{name}} likes are:
  {{#each myfruits}}
    {{kind}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Have a look at this updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/214/edit).

You should however reset your local store adapter's data to avoid multiple entries after each application initialization. I've done it by creating a pseudo random suffix for the namespace of the `LSAdapter`, but this could be anything you find more convenient.

```
App.LSAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.create({
  namespace: 'app-emberjs-'+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)
});
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

After reading your last comment and just to show how it looks like in the chrome debugger tools that the `LSAdapter` stores the data. Have a look at the below screenshot. Here I've reloaded 2 times the app, and as expected two namespaces are created. If you have the same namespace every time thing are going to overlap resulting in some unexpected behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. What if we just have the [same namespace](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/215/edit). If I refresh the page after some submissions, only the number of fruits remain, but not the kind of fruit. Do you know why?  I guess this has to with how LSAdapter saves relationships.

Comment: @HaoQiLi, have a look at my updated answer. I guess you need to have different namespaces to avoid overlaps that result in unexpected behavior...

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I'm just wondering why that behavior is there *if* the namespace is the same. I think the behavior sheds some light on how LSAdapter saves relationships. Thanks!

Comment: @HaoQiLi, I guess you might be right, I didn't have a chance to check the code of the `LSAdapter` but this could be the case indeed

Comment: I think I have figured out the reason for the names to not show up after a refresh. It's because `save()` is not called on the `App.Fruit.createRecord({kind:item, likedBy:[aperson.get('id')]})` currently.